# how to execute filter or aggregate or annotate on foreign key model in django

Tags: django

i have user model

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

and order model

```
class Order(models.Model):
        user = models.ForgienKey(User)
        product_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

creating 2 user

```
hi = User.objects.create(firs_name = 'hi')


bye = User.objects.create(firs_name = 'bye')
```

i created 3 orders

```
Order.objects.create(product_name='nokia',user=hi)
Order.objects.create(product_name='samsung',user=hi)
Order.objects.create(product_name='nokia',user=bye)
```

so how to count nokia has 2 users and samsung has 1 user in django using filter or aggregate or annotate? and ouput something like this(should in orderby count value)

```
{
 "nokia":"2",
"samsung":"1"
}
```

Django 1.8

Comment: if i use hi.Order_set.all() ====> gives <Order:nokia><order:samsung>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this you will get your output in json format

```
from django.db.models import Count
Order.objects.values('product_name')
             .annotate(usercount=Count('user'))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can you default count function to get the count of objects with or without the filter as per your need as following.

```
data_dict = {}
for cat in Order.objects.all()
    data_dict.update({cat.product_name : 0 })
for obj in Order.objects.all():
    if obj.product_name in data_dict.keys():
        data_dict[obj.product_name] += 1
```

printing data_dict will give you your expected output

Comment: i have 2000orders i can not able write data_dict={....} for all , it should be orderby max value please check the updated question

Answer (score 0):

```
objects.create(first_name = 'hi')
hi.save()

bye = User.objects.create(first_name = 'bye')
bye.save()
```

Here first_name should be same as field name in models.

```
l=[]
for o in Order.objects.all():
    l.append(str(o.product_name))
```

l is list which contains all products(repeated) in a list

```
d = {x:l.count(x) for x in l}
print d
```

d gives data in dictionary format, which is

```
{'nokia': 2, 'samsung': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following query

```
orders = Order.objects
             .values_list('product_name')
             .annotate(usercount=Count('user'))        
orders = dict(orders) # This must be of your json key values.
```

OR

```
orders = dict(orders.iterlists()) # This must be of your json key values.
```

Comment: @Para M : Could you find this answer useful or not?